# Using awk to only include column beginning with specific value?

Tags: regex, awk

I have a file with 7 columns with 192 million lines. I want to filter the file so it only has data beginning with `chr1_` and `chr7_` in the second column.

```
head file.txt.gz
gene_id variant_id  tss_distance    ma_samples  ma_count    maf pval_nominal    slope   slope_se
ENSG00000227232.5   chr1_13550_G_A_b38  -16003  16  16  0.0132231   0.329834    0.188778    0.193552
ENSG00000227232.5   chr1_14671_G_C_b38  -14882  12  12  0.00991736  0.618791    0.110828    0.222611
ENSG00000227232.5   chr2_14677_G_A_b38  -14876  60  60  0.0495868   0.378305    -0.090737   0.102905
ENSG00000227232.5   chr3_16841_G_T_b38  -12712  46  46  0.0380165   0.100419    -0.191008   0.116067
ENSG00000227232.5   chrX_16856_A_G_b38  -12697  10  10  0.00826446  0.708684    -0.0901965  0.241282
ENSG00000227232.5   chrX_17005_A_G_b38  -12548  18  18  0.014876    0.153674    -0.257458   0.180205
ENSG00000227232.5   chr4_17005_A_G_b38  -12548  18  18  0.014876    0.153674    -0.257458   0.180205
ENSG00000227232.5   chr7_17005_A_G_b38  -12548  18  18  0.014876    0.153674    -0.257458   0.180205
```

output:

```
head file.txt.gz
gene_id variant_id  tss_distance    ma_samples  ma_count    maf pval_nominal    slope   slope_se
ENSG00000227232.5   chr1_13550_G_A_b38  -16003  16  16  0.0132231   0.329834    0.188778    0.193552
ENSG00000227232.5   chr1_14671_G_C_b38  -14882  12  12  0.00991736  0.618791    0.110828    0.222611
ENSG00000227232.5   chr7_17005_A_G_b38  -12548  18  18  0.014876    0.153674    -0.257458   0.180205
```

The second column has data in the format `chrnumber _number_letter_letter_b38`. The number and letters can be different. E.g `chr4_17005_A_G_b38` or `ch7_17090_A_T_b38`. I just want the second column to begin with `chr1_` or `chr7_`. How would I do this using `awk`?

I have tired

```
gunzip -c file.txt.gz | awk '$2 ~ /^chr1/' > output.txt
```

However the output also contains chr19 and chr10. Everything with 1. I am also unsure how to include chr7.

Comment: This question was discussed on meta [Failed an audit because I flagged as duplicate when it really is one - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421570/failed-an-audit-because-i-flagged-as-duplicate-when-it-really-is-on). ■ @TedLyngmo Repost from meta: [we should close the older question as duplicate of the newer, if the newer is better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-). A bit unfortunate in this case (because of the OP behavior) but regardless it still seems to be the best strategy here.

Comment: @user202729 Yes, I can see how that can be a good thing. In this case the original question and this were pretty much the same and the answer I made a day before the accepted answer here is pretty much the same too. In such cases I'd vote for the older version to stay but well well, history now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use:

```bash
gunzip -c file.txt.gz | awk '$2 ~ /^chr[17]_/' > output.txt
```

`^chr[17]_` will match `chr1_` or `chr7_` right after start position. By adding `_` we make sure that we don't match `chr10` or `chr75`.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> gunzip -c file.txt.gz | awk '$2 ~ /^chr1/' > output.txt
> ```
>
> However the output also contains chr19 and chr10. Everything with 1. I am also unsure how to include chr7?

You are close, but as you've noticed, `^chr1` will match anything starting with `chr1` but not match `chr7`.

You could filter on if `$2` starts with `chr1_` or `chr7_` with a regex that matches on either `1` or `7` followed by a `_`:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^chr[17]_/'
```

This however removes the headers from the output. If you want the first line(s) kept too:

```
awk 'NR < 2 || $2 ~ /^chr[17]_/'
```

Replace `2` if you want more or less header lines.

Answer (score 2):

For checking if text starts with another text you might use [`index`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function, let `file.txt` content be

```
gene_id variant_id  tss_distance    ma_samples  ma_count    maf pval_nominal    slope   slope_se
ENSG00000227232.5   chr1_13550_G_A_b38  -16003  16  16  0.0132231   0.329834    0.188778    0.193552
ENSG00000227232.5   chr1_14671_G_C_b38  -14882  12  12  0.00991736  0.618791    0.110828    0.222611
ENSG00000227232.5   chr2_14677_G_A_b38  -14876  60  60  0.0495868   0.378305    -0.090737   0.102905
ENSG00000227232.5   chr3_16841_G_T_b38  -12712  46  46  0.0380165   0.100419    -0.191008   0.116067
ENSG00000227232.5   chrX_16856_A_G_b38  -12697  10  10  0.00826446  0.708684    -0.0901965  0.241282
ENSG00000227232.5   chrX_17005_A_G_b38  -12548  18  18  0.014876    0.153674    -0.257458   0.180205
ENSG00000227232.5   chr4_17005_A_G_b38  -12548  18  18  0.014876    0.153674    -0.257458   0.180205
ENSG00000227232.5   chr7_17005_A_G_b38  -12548  18  18  0.014876    0.153674    -0.257458   0.180205
```

then

```
awk 'index($2,"chr1_")==1||index($2,"chr7_")==1' file.txt
```

gives output

```
ENSG00000227232.5   chr1_13550_G_A_b38  -16003  16  16  0.0132231   0.329834    0.188778    0.193552
ENSG00000227232.5   chr1_14671_G_C_b38  -14882  12  12  0.00991736  0.618791    0.110828    0.222611
ENSG00000227232.5   chr7_17005_A_G_b38  -12548  18  18  0.014876    0.153674    -0.257458   0.180205
```

Explanation: `index` function does return position of start of substring if found otherwise `0`, therefore `1` indicate that it is at beginning. I check for all strings you have enumerated and join them using logical OR (`||`).

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

One `awk` idea:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1 || ($2 ~ /^(chr1_|chr7_)/)' allpairs.txt
gene_id variant_id  tss_distance    ma_samples  ma_count    maf pval_nominal    slope   slope_se
ENSG00000227232.5   chr1_13550_G_A_b38  -16003  16  16  0.0132231   0.329834    0.188778    0.193552
ENSG00000227232.5   chr1_14671_G_C_b38  -14882  12  12  0.00991736  0.618791    0.110828    0.222611
ENSG00000227232.5   chr7_17005_A_G_b38  -12548  18  18  0.014876    0.153674    -0.257458   0.180205
```